# Remove TabLayout left and right padding

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using tab layout and here is my code

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="fixed"

        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabTextColor="#000"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"

        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />
```

Adding tab like this

//Creating tab

TextView tab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tab.setText("Home");
    tab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.ic_home_black_24dp, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab));

```
TextView tab2 = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tab2.setText("Report");
tab2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.ic_trending_up_black_24dp, 0, 0);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab2));

TextView tab3 = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tab3.setText("Medicine");
tab3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.ic_home_black_24dp, 0, 0);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab3));

TextView tab4 = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tab4.setText("More");
tab4.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.ic_trending_up_black_24dp, 0, 0);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab4));
```

and here is my phone screenshot

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYNs1.png
```

Two  things
1.How can I remove space which is taking from left and right of tab layout ?

2.How can I change the color of text and icon of active and inactive tab

Comment: use app:tabPadding  property

Answer (score 15):

1. to remove Padding from Tabs in Tab Layout

   In your TabLayout you have to set tabPaddingEnd and tabPaddingStart to 0dp.

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
   app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"/>
   ```
2. change color of icon of the selected tab of TabLayout by

   ```
   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
   setupViewPager(viewPager);

   tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
   tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
           new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {

               @Override
               public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                   super.onTabSelected(tab);
                   int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabSelectedIconColor);
                   tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
               }

               @Override
               public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                   super.onTabUnselected(tab);
                   int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabUnselectedIconColor);
                   tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
               }

               @Override
               public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                   super.onTabReselected(tab);
               }
           }
   );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For adjust pading you can use `app:tabMinWidth` like or `tabPaddingStart/tabPaddingEnd/tabPaddingTop/tabPaddingBottom`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMinWidth="50dp"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="1dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="1dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="1dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="1dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabTextColor="#000"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"

        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />
```

For simply you can use below code for color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

and save it in drawable as `tab_color_selector.xml`

and use

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
```

so total code will be

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMinWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabTextColor="#000"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />
```

Give colors in `tab_background_selected` and `tab_background_unselected` like `#000000`. or use  `#000000` directly instead of `@color/tab_background_unselected`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_forum_tab"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorBtnBg"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="-1dp"
        style="@style/CustomTabLayoutStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

Set tabPaddingStart/tabPaddingEnd/tabPaddingTop/tabPaddingBottom like this.

```
    Styles:

    <style name="CustomTabLayoutStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/tab_text_selected</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/tab_indicator</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CustomTabTexStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabTexStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>

        ...
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the attr:

```
 app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
 app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
 app:tabMinWidth="0dp"
 app:tabPadding="0dp"
 app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
 app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
 app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
 app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
```